Doing "maximum p-value estimation" instead of maximum likelihood
Whenever we do maximum likelihood estimation, we look for the parameters that maximize the probability density of the data. On the other hand, when we compute p-values, we look at the tail probability of getting something at least as extreme as the data. This mismatch often leads to the data being an extreme outlier wrt the MLE parameters, in the sense that hypothesis testing at those parameters would show it having a very low p value. See end of post for an instance where this happens.
Is there a technique which maximizes the p-value rather than maximizing the likelihood? This would mean that we're looking for the parameters such that our sample is "most typical" rather than most likely, basically.
Of course there are different ways one can do this - different tail probabilities, test statistics, etc. But anything that's in the basic direction of directly maximizing some tail probability derived from some sufficient statistic of the sample, rather than just maximizing the density, would be interesting.
For instance, suppose we have drawn a single $X$ uniformly from $[0, \theta]$, and we want to estimate $\theta$. The MLE is simply $\hat \theta = X$. However, supposing we use a two-sided hypothesis test with that value of $\hat \theta$ as the null hypothesis, $X$ is an extreme outlier with a p-value of 0. Choosing $\hat \theta$ to maximize this p-value instead gives $\hat \theta = 2X$, which in this situation also agrees with the MVUE. If we try this with a sample of two values taken from $[0,\theta]$, this estimator suggests $\hat \theta = \max(X_1, X_2)\sqrt 2$, which is different from both the MVUE and the min-MSE estimator, but interesting in its own right. In general, for a sample of size $n$, we end up choosing $\hat \theta$ so that the maximum element of this sample is at the median of the sampling distribution. So we get something quite sensible and perhaps very interesting.

"This mismatch often leads to the data failing a hypothesis test at their own MLE parameters."  That's a strange way to look at it, methinks. "Failing" a hypothesis test happens when there is not enough evidence in the data against the null hypothesis to lead to that hypothesis being discarded by the hypothesis test method. That lack of evidence is not down to a difference between p-values and likelihood functions.

The p-value as a function of null hypothesis has a maximum where the null hypothesis is equal to the observed effect. Are you are after something else?

Not sure what you mean - how does this relate to the example I gave above with $X$ and $[0, \theta]$, for instance?

Doesn’t this just mean that you estimate the parameter as the value hypothesized under the null hypothesis?

Not in the situation above. The "null hypothesis" is dependent on the parameter. We choose a parameter and then compute the p-value of (some sufficient statistic of) the sample given that parameter as the null hypothesis, and then look for the parameter maximizing this quantity.

This isn't exactly what you're asking, but you may be interested in reading about "Fiducial Inference". (This really answers the question "How can we turn a p-value into a confidence interval" rather than your question "How can we turn a p-value into a point estimate", but it may still be of interest).

@JohnMadden Have you a reference for "How can we turn a p-value into a confidence interval" involving Fiducial Inference. I know about the fiducial 'confidences' talked about in the confidence distribution literature, but they do not have frequency interpretations.

@GrahamBornholt yes yes indeed I should have said "Interval estimate" rather than "confidence interval"

Leaving aside some issues with the question as sit presently stands (which is why I am not posting an answer just yet), "minimum chi-square" is an example (among a number of others) of an estimation method where we minimize some lack of fit test statistic, which would indeed correspond (albeit indirectly) to "maximizing a p value". Similarly one can use other "goodness of fit"/"lack of fit" statistics to produce estimates.

I've adjusted the wording slightly and added another example. I think what I am asking is clear enough at this point, and am hoping to get feedback on the mathematical idea being expressed instead of the wording.

I would advise strongly against using examples where a single observation is used to estimate a parameter of a statistical model because it is likely to be an example where overfitting leads to aberrant behaviour. See here for an important (but underrecognised) example: https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.08394

I think that you should consider your own question in light of an example of a normal distribution. You will then probably be able to see what my second comment and @Dave 's mean.

I chose this distribution specifically for this reason, @MichaelLew. You get the same problem with any sample of size $N$ from the distribution of $[0, \theta]$. (I do now realize, though, the result I got basically only happens if we're doing a two-sided hypothesis test, which doesn't necessarily work so well since $\theta > X$; we'd rather do a right-tailed one instead, and maximizing that p-value would lead to $\theta \to \infty$.)
